# Unresolved reference 'BaseHTTPServer'

Tags: python, http, reference, pycharm, webserver

I'm trying to create webserver and run this code but getting the error Unresolved reference 'BaseHTTPServer'. Any help would be appreciated

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
    def main():
        try:
            port = 8080
            server = HTTPServer(('',port), webserverhandler)
            print('Web Server is running %s' %port)
    
        except: KeyboardInterrupt:
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.x, you should replace your import statement by:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
```